# Line continuation of strings in Fortran

Tags: string, fortran

How does one break a long string and continue on a next line in Fortran?

I just started using gfortran 4.7.2 in Fedora 17. When I tried to use the following a test code, I am not getting output:

```
    PROGRAM test_ampersand
    IMPLICIT NONE
    PRINT *, 'I am a new learner of' &
     'fortran'
    END PROGRAM test_ampersand
```

I was expecting the output as:

```
I am a new learner of fortran
```

Comment: Most of the times, it is also useful to include compiler error message if the program does compile, or a run-time error message if the program compiles but does not run.

Answer (score 11):

This should work too:

```
PRINT *, 'I am a new learner of &
     &fortran'
```

That is, character literals can be continued across line breaks but each continuation line must have an ampersand in the first non-blank position.

Comment: When I used gfortran, following message appeared:               PRINT *, 'I am a new learner of &                                 
                                1
Error: Unterminated character constant beginning at (1)
Ampersand.f:8.10:
             &fortran'                                                      
          1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)

Answer (score 7):

The way statement continuation works in free-form source is to transform the statement of the question to

```
print *, 'I am a new learner of'      'fortran'
```

This isn't a valid thing.  Naturally, one could write

```
print *, 'I am a new learner of'//' fortran'
```

or

```
print *, 'I am a new learner of', 'fortran'
```

and possibly see much the same effect.

However, as noted in the other answers, literal characters may be continued over line boundaries in free-form source using a special form of statement continuation:

```
print *, 'I  am a new learner of &
          &fortran'
```

Usually one often sees free-form statement continuation with simply the `&` on the non-terminating line as in the question. Within this so-called *character context*, though, we must have an `&` on the continuation line and on the continuing line the statement continues with the character immediately following the `&`, and within the same character context.

For fixed-form source, however, things are different.

```
      print *, 'I am a new learner of'
     1'fortran'
```

is like

```
      print *, 'I am a new learner of'    'fortran'  ! Lots of spaces ignored
```

which is again an invalid statement.  Using

```
      print *, 'I am a new learner of
     1fortran'
```

is a valid statement, but again suffers from all those spaces up to column 72.

One could use string concatenation here:

```
      print *, 'I am a new learner of '//
     1         'fortran'
```

or simply break the line at column 72 (for after all, we're doing this because of the lines being long).

Answer (score 4):

When continuing the line in question, you need either a comma, which is needed when printing multiple variables or literal constants on one line, or string concatenation `//`, to concatenate two character strings into one.

This will work:

```
PRINT *, 'I am a new learner of ', &
     'fortran'
```

This will work too:

```
PRINT *, 'I am a new learner of '// &
     'fortran'
```

Comment: When I followed above suggestions using gfortran, error message was as:                                                             PRINT *, 'I am a new learner of ', &                              
                                   1
Error: Expected expression in PRINT statement at (1)              PRINT *, 'I am a new learner of '// &                             
                                          1
Error: Syntax error in expression at (1)
Ampersand.f:6.9:       'fortran'                                                                1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)

Answer (score 2):

In the old code I'm editing the ampersand must appear in the second line after exactly 5 spaces; all other non-comment lines in this code begin with 6 spaces:

```
      PROGRAM test_ampersand
      IMPLICIT NONE
      PRINT *, 'I am a new learner of'
     & 'fortran'
      END PROGRAM test_ampersand
```

This has to do with which version of fortran the compiler is expecting, which it may be inferring from the code.  Because I am editing legacy code, I have to follow the FORTRAN 77 style.  What you describe is the Fortran 95 style.

You can indicate a language version in the filename extension (e.g. `.f08` rather than `.f`) or with [compiler options](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gfortran) (e.g. `-std=f2008`).  If you are not constrained to an older version, it's probably best to use the most recent version.

(All of the fixed column requirements are related to how early versions of Fortran were encoded on punch cards; newer versions provide other options.)

Comment: `-std=f2008` cannot help. This is not controlled by the standard version but by the source form (fixed form vs. free form). It is perfectly legal and possible to have Fortran 2008 source in fixed form. The suffix does indicate the form, but some compilers do not accept `.f08`, but only `.f90`. The .f90 does not mean Fortran 90, it means free form fortran source. It is confusing, but it is how it works.