# Continue strings into next line in Fortran 77

Tags: fortran, fortran77, intel-fortran

I have this code in FORTRAN 77 (I have to use this because it is used as a subroutine for my Abaqus program) where I am asking the subroutine to print my stresses and strain results, for each element and after each time increment, in a particular place. Now, my directory path is long (because of several reasons). Therefore, I have to write the path to the directory in two lines since FORTRAN 77 only recognizes anything written between columns 6 to 77 (I believe!).

Now, I have tried many things!

I have put & symbol at column 6 on the next line, a number (like 1) at column 6 on the next line, and even a star symbol (*) at the same place!

However, I keep getting error# 5082!

Here is the part of the code that is not being accepted in ifort compiler:

```
     subroutine uvarm(uvar,direct,t,time,dtime,cmname,orname,
    1 nuvarm,noel,npt,layer,kspt,kstep,kinc,ndi,nshr,coord,
    2 jmac,jmatyp,matlayo,laccfla)

     include 'aba_param.inc'

     character*80 cmname, orname
     character*3 flgray(15)
     character*80 file1, file2

     dimension uvar(nuvarm),direct(3,3),t(3,3),time(2)
     dimension array(15),jarray(15),jmac(*),jmatyp(*),coord(*)

C      integer i

     call getvrm('E',array,jarray,flgray,jrcd,jmac,jmatyp,
   1 matlayo,laccfla)

     uvar(1) = array(1)
     uvar(2) = array(2)
     uvar(3) = array(4)

     call getvrm('S',array,jarray,flgray,jrcd,jmac,jmatyp,
   1 matlayo,laccfla)

     uvar(4) = array(1)
     uvar(5) = array(2)
     uvar(6) = array(4)

    file1 = '/gpfs/work/m/mfg5310/fracture/ResearchWork'
  1 '/fracture_subroutines/frac_in_mid_Mode2_case1_strains.txt'
    file2 = '/gpfs/work/m/mfg5310/fracture/ResearchWork'
  2 '/fracture_subroutines/frac_in_mid_Mode2_case1_stress.txt'

    open(unit=101,file=file1)
    open(unit=103,file=file2)

    write(101,350) uvar(1),uvar(2),uvar(3),coord(1),coord(2)

    write(103,350) uvar(4),uvar(5),uvar(6),coord(1),coord(2)

350 format(e12.5,6x,e12.5,6x,e12.5,6x,e12.5,6x,e12.5)


C      close(unit=101)
C      close(unit=103)

    return
    end
```

What should I do?

I know I can always shorten the path so that the entire directory fits in one line. But for two reasons, I want to know how to continue the string into the next line in Fortran 77:

Reason 1: I just really want to know this.
Reason 2: The files printed are more organized this way! I will be able to name the file exactly what I want to.

Comment: Welcome Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questons. Also post complete error message, not just the number. I have no idea what is #5082.

Comment: Always post compmete error outputs. The compier prints more important information, not just the code. Also, you do not have to use just Fortran 77 for Abaqus. You can use any Fortran understood by Intel Fortran, even Fortran 2008. Perhaps you need to use fixed form source, but that is something different. You cn use any Fortran version in fixed form source.

Comment: You are not coding in Fortran 77. You are using fixed source form. You would benefit from understanding the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the Fortran string concatenation operator // like this

```
      file1 = '/gpfs/work/m/mfg5310/fracture/ResearchWork'//
     & '/fracture_subroutines/frac_in_mid_Mode2_case1_strains.txt'
```

Comment: Welcome, please notice there are already votes in place to close this question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776270/line-continuation-with-gfortran-4-7-2  Please try not to answer obvious duplicate questions in the future. You can always add a new question to the original duplicate question. Just by a small quirk in the rules I was not able to close this question immediately.

Comment: And notice that using the concatenation is NOT necessary as explained by some answers there.

Comment: I disagree, the linked "duplicate question" refers to free form Fortran (Fortran 90 or later) while this question relates to fixed form Fortran 77. The procedure for string continuation is very different.

Comment: OK. It doesn't do so explicitly and one can easily answer both variants at one place, but we will have to disagree then.

Comment: If you read the comments on the answers to the other question, you may conclude that that question actually _is_ about fixed-form source.

Comment: I think it is not nice to downvote this answer if it was just because of the duplication. I hope whoever voted up or down did so because of the content only.